# CMIS Sharepoint 2013 - Cannot Update Document

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, opencmis, dotcmis

I cannot update a document using CMIS for Sharepoint 2013. I keep getting an error "The operation is attempting to update an object that is no longer current." and I am stuck as to why that is.

Please can you check what is wrong with my code below:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
        parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = url;
        parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.User] = username;
        parameters[DotCMIS.SessionParameter.Password] = password;
        parameters[SessionParameter.RepositoryId] = repositoryID;

        SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
        ISession session = factory.CreateSession(parameters);
        ICmisObject cmisobj = session.GetObject("12345");

        IDictionary<String, Object> properties = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        properties["cmis:name"] = "MyNewName";

        IObjectId newId = cmisobj.UpdateProperties(properties);
```

Thanks for the reply. I tried adding the IOperationContext but I am still getting the same error. Am I implementing it wrong?

```
        SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
        ISession session = factory.CreateSession(parameters);

        IOperationContext oc = session.CreateOperationContext();
        ICmisObject cmisobj = session.GetObject("12345", oc);

        IDictionary<String, Object> properties = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        properties["cmis:name"] = "MyNewName";

        IObjectId newId = cmisobj.UpdateProperties(properties);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known SharePoint bug. It fails with this error if you include a change token (property "cmis:changeToken") in your update request. DotCMIS automatically adds this property in order to prevent lost updates.

To exclude the change token you must not request it when get the object. 
Call `GetObject()` with an `IOperationContext` object, which has a property filter that not contains "cmis:changeToken". SharePoint will then accept the update request.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried adding the IOperationContext but am still getting the same error

            SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
            ISession session = factory.CreateSession(parameterconfiguration);

            IOperationContext oc = session.CreateOperationContext();
            ICmisObject cmisobj = session.GetObject("12345", oc);
            
            IDictionary<String, Object> properties = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            properties["cmis:name"] = "NewName";

            IObjectId newId = cmisobj.UpdateProperties(properties);

Comment: You missed a step. Add this line before calling GetObject():  `oc.FilterString = "cmis:objectId,cmis:objectTypeId,cmis:name"; // add all the properties you need here`